# Retrieving list variable value defined in a method in a class into visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I am trying to retrieve the list variable into visualforce page which i have defined in a method inside apex extension class. I am getting error, could anyone please help. In the below code in vf page i am trying to access the list dRange which i have defined in extension class.

VF Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection >
            <table border="1" name="LeaveView" value="{!Submit}">
                <tr><th>LeaveView</th>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!dRange}">
                        <th> </th>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tr>        
            </table>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Apex Extension Class:

```
public string Submit(){

    this.l = (LeaveTracker__c)controller.getRecord();        
    Date spDate=l.Sprint_Start_Date__c;
    String tm=l.Team_Names__c;
    List<Date> dRange=new List<Date>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i<=13; i++){
        dRange.add(spDate);
        spDate=spDate+1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<Date> dRang` is a local variable to the `Submit()` method. You cannot access it in VF page.

To access it in VF page, declare it as a class level variable.

```
public class MyExtension{
    public List<Date> dRange {get;set;}

    public MyExtension(){
        dRange = new List <Date>();
    }


    public string Submit(){

        this.l = (LeaveTracker__c)controller.getRecord();        
        Date spDate=l.Sprint_Start_Date__c;
        String tm=l.Team_Names__c;
        for(Integer i = 0; i<=13; i++){
            dRange.add(spDate);
            spDate=spDate+1;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to access `dRange` because it is the local variable inside your `submit` method. You can access only those variables in `visualforce` page which are declared as `properties` i.e. with `getters` and `setters`

So, you will have to declare `dRange` as a property in your `controller` in order for you to access it in `visualforce` page

```
public List<Date> dRange {get;set;}
```

And in your method, you should initialize it wherever you will be using it first, and then add values to it.

```
dRange=new List<Date>();
for(Integer i = 0; i<=13; i++){
    dRange.add(spDate);
    spDate=spDate+1;
}
```

Also, you cannot call the `submit` method from `<table>`, I would suggest you can move all your code from `submit` method to `controller's` `constructor`, so your `controller's` `constructor` code will be

```
public List<Date> dRange {get;set;}
public controllerName(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.l = (LeaveTracker__c)controller.getRecord();        
    Date spDate=l.Sprint_Start_Date__c;
    String tm=l.Team_Names__c;
    dRange=new List<Date>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i<=13; i++){
        dRange.add(spDate);
        spDate=spDate+1;
    }
}
```

And regarding `visualforce` page, not sure how you are trying to display but you can directly use the property in `repeat` tag without using the `submit` method.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!dRange}" var="d">
    <th>{!d}</th>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Yes you are right, in a jiffy I forgot about setter and getters.